# An unhandled exception of type 'System.InvalidOperationException' occurred in System.Data.dll 430

Tags: c#

the da.fill(ds) is giving me an An unhandled exception of type 'System.InvalidOperationException' occurred in System.Data.dll

I'm not 100% sure why this error is here but I know it appeared after I attempted this login code.

```
 using (SqlConnection con = new SqlConnection("Data Source=c:\\RegistrationMDB.accdb"))
            {
                SqlDataAdapter da = new SqlDataAdapter();
                DataSet ds = new DataSet();
                SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand("SELECT ID, PASSWORD FROM Students WHERE ID = @ID OR PASSWORD = @PASSWORD", con);
                cmd.CommandType = CommandType.StoredProcedure;

                cmd.Parameters.Add("@ID", SqlDbType.VarChar).Value = id;
                cmd.Parameters.Add("@PASSWORD", SqlDbType.VarChar).Value = pw;


                da.Fill(ds);
                foreach (DataRow dr in ds.Tables[0].Rows)
                {
                    iD = (dr["@ID"].ToString());
                    password = dr["@PASSWORD"].ToString();
                }

                if (iD == id && password == pw)
                {
                    return true;
                }
                else
                {
                    LogNotification = "ID/Password is incorrect";
                    return false;
                }
            }
        }
```

Comment: Would you agree that when you call da.Fill(ds) - ds is empty.

Answer (score 0):

```
da.SelectCommand = cmd;
```

Before `da.Fill(ds);`